# Find first instance of a pattern in Lua and remove it from string

Tags: string, lua, string-formatting, lua-patterns

I get strings in the following format:

```
abc:321,cba:doodoo,hello:world,eat:mysh0rts
```

I'd like to grab one instance of the data pairing from the string and remove it from the string, so for example if I wanted to grab the value following `hello:world` I'd like this to happen:

```
local helloValue, remainingString = GetValue("hello")
```

Which will return `world` for `hellovalue` and `abc:321,cba:doodoo,eat:mysh0rts` for `remainingString`.

I'm doing this rather cumbersomely with loops, what would a better way of doing it be?

Comment: It's better to show what you are doing, so that we know how to improve.

Comment: What's your expected output, if the input is `abc:321,cba:doodoo,eat:mysh0rts,hello:world` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
local str = 'abc:321,cba:doodoo,hello:world,eat:mysh0rts'

local t = {}
for k, v in str:gmatch('(%w+):(%w+)') do
    if k ~= 'hello' then
        table.insert(t, k .. ':' .. v)
    else
        helloValue = v
    end
end

remainingString = table.concat(t, ',')
print(helloValue, remainingString)
```

You can turn this to a more general `GetValue` function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
local str = 'abc:321,cba:doodoo,hello:world,eat:mysh0rts'

function GetValue(s,k)
    local p=k..":([^,]+),?"
    local a=s:match(p)
    local b=s:gsub(p,"")
    return a,b
end

print(GetValue(str,"hello"))
print(GetValue(str,"eat"))
```

If you want to parse the whole string into key-value pairs, try this:

```
for k,v in str:gmatch("(.-):([^,]+),?") do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(hello:[^,]+,)
```

Just do a replace with `empty string`.The replace data and `$1` are the things you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/24

Comment: The question was mistakenly tagged with **regex**, Lua pattern isn't regular expression, so this won't work.